# Unable to resolve service for type ASP.NET Core DI

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-standard

Seeing some bizarre scenario where I am getting a DI error in a .NET Standard 2.0 CL service when calling a Controller that uses it.

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VideoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVideoService _videoService;

    public VideoController(IVideoService videoService)
    {
        _videoService = videoService;
    }
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public List<Video> GetVideos()
    {
        return _videoService.GetVideos().Result.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Service in CL**

```
public class VideoService : IVideoService
{
    private readonly ILogger log;
    private readonly ConfigWrapper config;

    private readonly IAzureMediaServicesHelpers amsHelpers;
    private readonly IStorageHelpers storageHelpers;

    public VideoService(ILogger logger, ConfigWrapper _config, IAzureMediaServicesHelpers _amsHelper, IStorageHelpers _storageHelper)
    {
        log = logger;
        config = _config;
        amsHelpers = _amsHelper;
        storageHelpers = _storageHelper;
    }
```

**Startup in .NET Core project**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IStorageHelpers, StorageHelpers>();
    services.AddTransient<IAzureMediaServicesHelpers, AzureMediaServicesHelpers>();
    services.AddTransient<IVideoService, VideoService>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The error I get is the typical middleware exception

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate Demo.Shared.VideoService'.

I am not using Logger here because this CL is also used by am Azure Function that does not support Logger. I assume I am missing something easy.

Comment: You still need to tell the DI framework what to do with the `ILogger`. A simple but hacky solution would be to create a dummy implementatoin of ILogger and use that.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: Well it's your code, only you can say what `ILogger` looks like.

Comment: So I create a copy if ILogger (write my own log.Error etc)? Can't I register an instance of ILogger somewhere?

Comment: Assuming this is the standard ASP.NET MVC Core `ILogger`, then there should already be one available for you to use... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: If I use the DefaultBuilder in ASP.NET Core, all the ILogger goodness is there. So what is going on here? https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs

Answer (score 0):

Working as intended. Make a class that matches the ILogger which 'does nothing' and register it. One day you may want to replace that dummy with a real logging method.

```
From the DLL: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging


Class MyLovelyClass
    Implements Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger

    Public Sub Log(Of TState)(logLevel As LogLevel, eventId As EventId, state As TState, exception As Exception, formatter As Func(Of TState, Exception, String)) Implements ILogger.Log
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Function IsEnabled(logLevel As LogLevel) As Boolean Implements ILogger.IsEnabled
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function BeginScope(Of TState)(state As TState) As IDisposable Implements ILogger.BeginScope
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: How does this work? I actually want to log things. If I have a dummy class it won't do anything.

Comment: Seems you've solved your own problem. Jump straight to making a compliant logger that DOES log then :)

Comment: My confusion is that I am using DefaultBuilder in ASP.NET Core. So all this should be done for me. https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs

Comment: The DI only knows what you register in it. No magic. Do one of the solutions, or don't.

Comment: But the DefaultBuilder registers it as well. If I do not DI the service, the controller works fine and logger works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ILogger<VideoService>` instead of ILogger. Try to change VideoService constructor like this:

```
public VideoService(ILogger<VideoService> logger, ConfigWrapper _config, IAzureMediaServicesHelpers _amsHelper, IStorageHelpers _storageHelper)
```